# Play video when slide is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, onclick, slider

I am creating a slider with images that when someone clicks one slide, opens a modal window with another slider with videos.

What I would like to achieve is: on click -> play the video. So if the third slide of the images is clicked, open and play the video automatically.

[Here is a fiddle with the example](https://fiddle.jshell.net/hhLy4cng/13/), but the play is not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<iframe id="vimeo-player" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/218392001?color=637df2?api=1&autoplay=1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

> You have to add &autoplay=1&loop=1 after ?api=1 to iframe

Comment: &autoplay=1 plays the video even if the slide is not clicked, so if you wait 10 secs and you click the slide, the video would be already playing... What I need is on click, start playing the video

Comment: so you can do one thing, on click add that value to video player. Isn't it fine?

Comment: You're right. That could work. I've modified my code so it says: var iframe = $('#vimeo-player')[0].src += "&autoplay=1"; but it's just adding it to the first iframe. Do you know why?

Comment: $('#vimeo-player')[0] is first frame. not all frams. That's why its getting added to the first frame.

Comment: And what do I have to do to apply that to all iframes?

Comment: first of all, click event is not working. Thats why play() is not getting invoked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145187/discussion-between-sinchan-and-patie).